# Find all positive integers $n$ that have two prime factors, and such that $n$ has three times fewer divisors than $n^2$

Tags: number-theory

I am having trouble finding all positive integers $n$ that have two prime factors, and such that $n$ has three times fewer divisors than $n^2$.  I wasn't sure if I need to use Tau or if it can be just figured out using basic number theory.  Any help?

Comment: What does "three times fewer" mean? Do you mean $n^2$ has $3$ times as many factors as $n$? Usually, it is better to say "one third as many" rather than "three times fewer," which is a confusing phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n=p^rq^s$ with $p\ne q$ prime and $r,s\ge 1$.
Then $n$ has $\tau(n)=(r+1)(s+1)$ divisors.
Similarly $n^2$ has $(2r+1)(2s+1)$ divisors.
You need to solve
$$ (2r+1)(2s+1) = 3(r+1)(s+1).$$
This is equivalent to $rs-r-s-2=0$, i.e. $(r-1)(s-1)=3$. 
hence $r=2,s=4$ (or vice versa, which corresponds to switching $p$ and $q$). Thus the smallest example is $n=144$.